# Identifying the user location - (Office or Home)

Tags: javascript, networking, ip, cidr

While trying to capture IP address of the user visiting the webpage, I am trying to match the Ip address with the organization's CIDR range to confirm if the user is on the organization network or home network. I used below code to capture IP address, does it make sense to do it this way? Any suggestions?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 function getIP() {
  fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      alert(`Your IP address is ${data.ip}`);
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));
}

getIP();
  </script>
```

Comment: Using the remote IP address that is reported on the server side is probably far more reliable than using some remote API on the client side.

Comment: So, I can write a userscript that intercepts calls to `ipapi.co` and mocks the response to appear wherever I want to appear? Why design it like that? As @RobbyCornelissen says - why not just use the IP that the request already comes into your service with? Or if it's really about just a website, there is no service to connect to - then what difference does it make which network are you using? Overall, this seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I am still learning on networking side of things, I didnt get which IP on server side we talking about? @RobbyCornelissen & VLAZ